# How to use CDI and JSF on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: jsf, tomcat, cdi

I thought that it would be easy to replace JSF bean by CDI bean.  But it's being a slow start.  Very slow.

I'm using Tomcat 8.5 and JSF 2.2, and I'm trying to use CDI.  I tried different configurations, with different results but nothing works, so, I follow the orientation in http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html and that's what I got.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Workflow]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My configurations are:

**\META-INF\Context.xml**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<Context reloadable="true">
<Resources            cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="20000"        />

<Resource 
name="jdbc/FlowDB" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="30" 
maxWait="10000"
username="xxxx" 
password="xxxxxxxxxxx" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flow?autoReconnect=true" />

<Resource
name="mail/Session"
auth="Container"
type="javax.mail.Session"
mail.smtp.host="localhost"
mail.smtp.port="25"
mail.smtp.auth="true"
mail.smtp.user="xxxxx@localhost"
mail.smtp.password="123456" />

<!-- Binding BeanManager to JNDI --> 
<Resource 
name="BeanManager"  
auth="Container"
type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>

<!--                             -->

</Context>
```

**\WEB-INF\beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
>
</beans>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
<configuration>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
<version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<!--            <version>4.3.2.Final</version> -->
<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.30</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- SPRING DATA JPA - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api 'INFO: CDI @ViewScoped bean functionality unavailable' http://weld.cdi-spec.org/
--> 

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Primefaces -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Primefaces Theme -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/all-themes -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
<!-- <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId> -->
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Email -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>mail</artifactId>
<version>1.4.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
<version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>


<!-- JUnit » 4.12 -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- slf4j-log4j -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
<version>4.6.3</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I suspect that something may be wrong in my pom.xml, or with Tomcat 8.5, or with something else.  But there is not much left...

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can try considering [this link](https://musingsinjava.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/enabling-jsf-2-2-and-cdi-1-2-on-tomcat-8/)

Comment: Use tommee... way easier

Comment: That exception is unhelpful. It's basically a summary exception informing us that a WAR could not be deployed. You should read further back in server logs to find the root cause exception which actually caused the deployment fail. That part represents the answer to your question.

Comment: After looking furter at tomcat log, + information at the link deosha provided, I found out the problem.
I'll edit the post to include de aswer.

Comment: @SannonAragão: create an answer in an answer, not via an edit of the question. You can (and are even encouraged to) answer your own questions!

Comment: @Kukeltje: I just did it.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Seems that a library was missing, Java Annotation Indexer or Jandex, which I already tried before, but not at the right way obviously. Not the right set of libraries and/or not the right scope.

after apply this configurations

plus the dependency below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems to start working fine.

So, the relevant section of my POM.XML was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```